# How to validate the entered string in search box using Selenium With Node.js and Mocha chai

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js, chai

I want to validate the string which is entered in the "Google search box"

When I run the below code in Node.js it throws the following error:

```
Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
```

Here is my code:

```
var assert = require('assert'),
    test = require('selenium-webdriver/testing'),
    webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

test.describe('Google Search', function() {
    test.it('should work', function(done) {
        var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
            withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.firefox()).
            build();

        driver.get('http://www.google.com');

        var searchBox = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('q'));
        searchBox.sendKeys('simple programmer');
        searchBox.getAttribute('value').then(function(value) {
            assert.equal(value, 'simple programmer');
        });
        driver.quit();done();
    });
});
```

I am using Node.js version 5.6.0.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that creating the driver takes more than 2 seconds. You should create it in a `before` hook (and destroy it in an `after` hook). Also, there's no need to use `done` when you use `test.it` because what you get from `selenium-webdriver/testing` is not the stock Mocha but a Mocha that has been patched to hook into Selenium control flows. The error message you get is Mocha's stock error message which unfortunately is misleading when you use `selenium-webdriver/testing`. Here's a working file:

```
var assert = require('assert'),
    test = require('selenium-webdriver/testing'),
    webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

test.describe('Google Search', function() {
    var driver;
    test.before(function () {
        driver = new webdriver.Builder().
            withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.firefox()).
            build();
    });

    test.after(function () {
        driver.quit();
    });
    test.it('should work', function() {
        driver.get('http://www.google.com');

        var searchBox = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('q'));
        searchBox.sendKeys('simple programmer');
        searchBox.getAttribute('value').then(function(value) {
            assert.equal(value, 'simple programmer');
        });
    });
});
```